# Javascript too slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to read the size of an image and regulate its margin if its larger than 150 in height. But I'm always getting a '0' in the console when running this code:

```
        var coverImg;
        coverImg = document.getElementById('userCover');

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'code/submit/submitGetUserData.php',
                data: {id: userID, what: 'all'},
                async: false,
                success:function(data,status){
                    var dataArray = data.split(',');

                    document.getElementById('userAvatar').src = dataArray[0];
                    coverImg.src = dataArray[1];
                    $('#userName').text(dataArray[2]);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("error occured");

                },
                complete: function(){
                    console.log(coverImg.height);

                    if(document.getElementById('userCover').height > 150)
                    {
                        var regulate = 0;
                        regulate = (coverImg.height - 150) / 2;
                        regulate = regulate * (-1);



                        coverImg.style.marginTop = regulate;
                    }
                }
        });
```

Is JS too slow to read the height property?!

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: If you open developer tools in chrome or firefox and check time response was received for that ajax call, what does it say?

Comment: Synchronous ajax is generally considered to be a pretty bad idea.

Comment: javascript is not slow, what is slow is downloading the image from Cincinatti. Until that is done, we don't know the story size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the code currently placed in `complete` into `coverImg.onload` handler. For example:

```
coverImg.onload = function() {
   if(document.getElementById('userCover').height > 150) {
     var regulate = (150 - this.height) / 2;
     // ...
   }
}
coverImg.src = dataArray[1];
```

... as browser can determine the height of `<img>` element only after it's fully loaded - and `complete` callback is fired before that.